# rhombus shaped view react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, view, react-native

Is it possible to create a rhombus shaped View using react-native?

Here is the picture for what I want:

[image]

I tried it using border styling but was unable to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution here:https://rnplay.org/apps/58FEmw

just need to add this styling:

```
transform: [
      {rotate: '45deg'}
    ]
```